# What happens with address of operator for variables that the compiler decides to put in registers?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, compiler-optimization

I understand that in C, if a variable is explicitly specified with the `register` keyword, then one cannot use the `&` operator on it, and that makes sense to me that there's no such thing as "address" of a variable that's always kept in a register.

My question is, if the compiler decides on its own to store a variable in register rather than spilling it, then what happens with the `&` operator during code execution?

I can think of two ways that the compiler might try to handle this:

1. Try to emulate the `&` behavior, but this seems hairy and I have no idea how one would do this rigorously and efficiently.
2. Always spill a variable if the `&` operator is used with this variable.

Does C take one of these approaches or does it do something else in this case?

Comment: Can you (or someone) explain what spill/spilling means in this context?

Comment: In theory, it can implement whatever behaviour is consistent and legal. There could be "magic" values that need to be checked for every time signify that a value is present in a register, though it would have to stay there the entire time the pointer is valid. In practice, it'll be stored in memory, and you'll get that address. That's much cheaper to do. Variables that only exist in registers mostly make sense for something with a short lifetime. Pointers usually make sense for objects with a longer lifetime (at least one function call/return from function call).

Comment: FWIW, registers in uCs are often accessible through a specific (reserved) addresses zones. It's up to the cross-compiler to resolve them correctly.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni We have to assume that the OP speaks of CPU core data/address registers ("accumulators" etc). Memory-mapped hardware registers is another story entirely.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Spilling means demoting a possibly in-register variable to memory. If you think of all available registers as a cup, then after using up all available registers to implement variables, all variables that couldn't fit into those available registers (the cup) spill into memory. Unoptimizable references to a variable via its address can make it go into memory (spill) even if all available registers haven't been used up. In that case the cup analogy doesn't work so well.

Comment: @PSkocik Great explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please note that what happens to non-`register` variables during optimization is beyond the scope of the C language. And there is yet another option: remove the variable entirely from the machine code.

> My question is, if the compiler decides on its own to store a variable in register rather than spilling it, then what happens with the & operator during code execution?

The compiler is not likely going to place a variable in a register if it spots the presence of the `&` operator. In fact every real-world compiler I have ever used will place such a variable either on the stack or in static storage memory, thereby making it addressable.

Comment: [Here is a counterexample](https://godbolt.org/z/ZeGxP5).

Comment: @NateEldredge Not really, that's rather "And there is yet another option: remove the variable entirely from the machine code." Since the compiler is using `edi` repeatedly, it doesn't actually allocate the variables other than as part of the `.text` instructions itself.

Comment: I replaced it with another example that I think illustrates it better.  I guess my point is that the mere *presence* of the `&` operator in the source doesn't necessarily force the variable to have an address; only if that address is actually needed in a way that can't be avoided by optimization.

Answer (score 6):

The fact that a variable is implemented in a hardware register or not has to be completely transparent to the user. It is up to the compiler to realize this such that the current value can always be accessed through the pointer.

That changes when the user decides to declare the variable with the keyword `register`. Then the use of the `&` operator is simply prohibited.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a compiler expert, but my impression is it's sort of the other way around.  First the compiler tries to optimize the code.  If after optimization, the address of the variable is not needed, then it is a candidate to be put in a register (or perhaps optimized completely out of existence).

Of course if the `&` operator is never applied to the variable at all, then it is certainly a candidate.  But even if `&x` does appear in the source code, the need for the address may go away after optimization.

As a trivial example, if we have

```
int x = 7;
foo(*&x);
```

the compiler can see that `*&x` is exactly equivalent to `x`, and so the code can be treated as if it were just `foo(x)`.  If the address of `x` is not taken anywhere else, then it no longer needs to have an address at all, and can go in a register.

Now you can imagine extending this sort of analysis to more complicated code.

```
    int x = foo1(), y = foo2();
    int *p;
    p = cond ? &x : &y;
    return *p;
```

[Try it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e5btt5)

Conceptually, this can be successively rewritten as

```
return *(cond ? &x : &y);
return cond ? *&x : *&y;
return cond ? x : y;
```

and now `x,y` no longer need to have addresses, and `p` no longer needs to exist at all.

So in other words, the compiler doesn't try to "emulate" the `&` operator; rather, it tries to restructure the code so that it simply isn't needed.

The most common situation where this is not possible is if the address of the variable is passed to another function.

```
int x;
foo(&x);
```

Unless `foo` can be inlined or some other sort of interprocedural analysis is available, the compiler really does have to pass the address of something to `foo`, and so `x` has to exist in memory, at least for that moment.  Of course, the compiler can choose to move it into a register immediately thereafter, and keep it there for the rest of the function if its address is not needed again; the question of whether a variable lives in memory or in a register need not be fixed for all time.

Answer (score 1):

Streaming compilers that generate assembly ASAP as they parse C code (e.g., tinycc) simply won't put variables in registers unless those variables have the `register` storage class specifier. A nonstreaming compiler that builds an abstract syntax tree, on the other hand, can decide whether to put something in a register only after it's seen the whole block. Then it can know for sure that the variable's address won't ever be needed (or that all accesses to the variable through its address can be optimized into direct register accesses).

Since C cannot interpret a dynamically inputted piece of C code at runtime within the context of its statically provided code (no `_Eval(read_string())` where the user could input `printf("%p\n",(void*)&some_local);`), there cannot be any surprise address-taking at runtime. After a C compiler is finished with a block, it knows how every local in it will ever be used.